# du shows completely different folder size for * and folder name

Tags: disk-usage

I'm trying to move some data over and to start with I'd like to make sure that the size is ok. I run into a problem however, if I check the folder with

```
du -sh  myfolder/
780M    myfolder/
```

but

```
du -sh *
..
71M     myfolder
..
```

I thought it might be something to do with hidden files but this particular folder does not have any inside.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have a ~709 MB file being added to / deleted from `myfolder` between operation?  A file being written to?  A file being linked to `myfolder`?  If you don't then it looks like a bug in your `du`.

Comment: Do you have hidden files?  `ls -lhA myfolder`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are that `myfolder` contains 709 MB worth of files that have another hard link in a subdirectory that is sorted lexicographically before `myfolder`. The `du` command reports each distinct file only the first time it sees it, so if a file has multiple links inside the tree(s) covered by a run of `du`, it's reported only once, under whichever directory was traversed first.

Here are a few ways you can look for hard links:

- `find myfolder -links +1 -type f` lists all the files that have at least a second hard link under `myfolder` (`+1` means “more than one”), regardless of where that link is.
- `find . -samefile myfolder/foo` (with GNU find) lists all the hard links to `myfolder/foo` under the current directory. Since `myfolder` is under the current directory, this includes `myfolder/foo` itself.
- `find -type f -links +1 -printf '%i %p\n' | sort -k1n` (with GNU find) produces a list of hard-linked files under the current directory, grouped by inode number. Two files are the same if they are located on the same filesystem and they have the same inode number.

Comment: This might be the case, I'll check this out. Thanks @Gillles

Comment: Yes, with `find . -samefile ...` I found multiple hard links all over the place, thanks again.

Comment: Following on the subject, `ls -l` displays a number next to the permissions which indicates a count of hard links on the file